# which software is better for creating and changing DYNAMIC disks(partitions)?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, dynamic-disk, basic-disk

i have a laptop that it's 1 TeraByte hard disk is dynamic(not basic).
i want to change that hard drive with a third party program for creating new patitions.
so i tried Acronis Disk Director Advanced (server) v11, but it seems it does not support dynamic disks.
i tried some other softwares, but they do n't support dynamic disks too.
would you please introduce me a good software for creating a partition from unallocated dynamic area!

**EDIT :**
i tried do that job with Disk Management(windows 7 - home **premium** edition), but after some changes i had a problem for booting system.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EaseUs](http://www.partition-tool.com/download.htm) will do it for you. However, not with the free version. The pro version is $20, not to much to ask. I have used the free version in the past and it worked well.

Here is their info on the resizing of dynamic discs: [Resize dynamic disk (Extend or shrink dynamic volume)](http://www.partition-tool.com/resource/resize-dynamic-disk.htm)

[Compare](http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/comparison.html) their versions.

Answer (score 1):

Home editions of Windows do not support dynamic disks as far as I know.

According to [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927520/en-us):

Dynamic discs are only supported for:

- Windows Vista Business
- Windows Vista Enterprise
- Windows Vista Ultimate.
- Windows 7 Enterprise
- Windows 7 Professional
- Windows 7 Ultimate
- Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter
- Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
- Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
- Windows Web Server 2008 R2

They are not supported for Windows Vista Home Basic, Windows Vista Home Premium, Windows 7 Home Basic, Windows 7 Starter, and Windows 7 Home Premium.

*There is one exception. When you upgrade your computer from Windows XP Media Center Edition to Windows Vista Home Premium, some dynamic discs are handled and supported.*

Comment: hi again. my os is windows 7 Home Premium and That Hard Disk is dynamic. however it works in that operating system. would you plz lead me to a good software for re-configure  my disk!

Comment: Home versions don’t come with a utility to manage them, but they *do* support (as in have drivers for) them (for read/write if not installation) if they are already in that format (ie, if some other tool or system creates them). So -1 because the above response does **not** answer the question (specifically, let alone in general). For example, if you dual-boot Vista Pro and Home on the same system, boot Pro, create a dynamic disk, then boot Home, the Home version can still read the dynamic disk.